# Multiple nodes in one slide using views slideshow or another module

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript, views

I have a slideshow using views_slideshow which displays the latest post from 4 different content types, I need the slide to show multiple contents (from different content types) in one slide, when you click next there should be another slide containing 4 nodes.

This image might explain you the scenario!
[image]

Comment: How do you want to connect them nodes? I mean, how does blog relate to page and so on? They aren't random, are they?

Comment: there are no relations between content types, the latest posts of each content type should display first( 1st slide), then the 2nd latest of all will display in the other slide.

Comment: Views Slideshow creates slides from records. Think database rows. So, to get them displayed together, you need to join them somehow. You will have the same problem with pretty much every module there is. If I'll get an idea how to solve this, I'll post an answer. Edit: forget it, I tried to ask about making query like that and got massively downvoted on stackoverflow. So don't count on me here - no query I could translate to Drupal.

Comment: I think you should try to use grouping to group all the "same level" nodes -> adjust the view markup with the view's templates -> apply the slideshow JS using a custom JS file (whatever library that will be)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to use like [Relation](http://www.drupal.org/project/relation) to tie these things together using a relation as `Slideshow Content` and then a field tacked onto the relation as `slide number`.

You should be able to then have any number of content types -- relate them to your slideshow and define the ordering as needed that content.

To ease the generation of relating (linking) things these additional relation modules may help:

[Relation Add](https://drupal.org/project/relation_add)

> Small block that allows the user to add an appropriate relation from
>   an entity page to any other appropriate entities, with a generic
>   autocomplete for each endpoint, and relation fields.

[Relation Autoconnect](https://drupal.org/sandbox/bobik/1256164)

> Module allows to setup invisible widget to Relation Dummy Field. This
>   widget loads information (entity type and ID) about another entity
>   from arguments in the path and create relation between determined and
>   newly created entity.
>
> For example, you can use path "node/add/story/node/22" to connect new
>   story content with node number 22.

[Relation Select](https://drupal.org/project/relation_select)

> This module provides a field widget for creating & editing relations.
>
> The selection interface is based on views. Use exposed filters to
>   search for entities, & select items from the view output displayed as
>   a clickable drop down list.

So the idea is you have all your content on the backend -- related via a Relation and its field to grab it for a Views Slideshow later. Some of these modules attempt to make creating that (meta-)relation with your slideshow content easier.

You might be able to use like [Arrange Fields](http://www.drupal.org/project/arrange_fields) or [FieldGroup](http://www.drupal.org/project/fieldgroup) to make a tab for "slideshow properies" for each of your content types that shows the Relation info in the node edit form.