# D6/views - Multiple nodes in one slide grouped by taxonomy

Tags: paging, views, javascript

I have the following taxonomy:

- food

  - **fruits**

    - *apples*
    - *pears*
    - *bananas*
  - **vegtables**

    - *tomatoes*
    - *carrot*
    - *cucumber*
  - **meat**

    - *chicken*
    - *beef*
    - *duck*

...and a view that brings all those items, currently as an html list grouped by taxonomy term. I use fields for each item.

I need to change my view in order to split them in slides (or pages with prev/next) so that each slide/page will hold **all** the items of a food subcategory (the whole group). Ideally with a slider but pagination will also suffice.

To be precise I'd like a similar result as in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76010/multiple-nodes-in-one-slide-using-views-slideshow-or-another-module). But in my case I have the above taxonomy tree to help distinct nodes I need in each slide

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might add an argument to your view.

The url of your view should looks like: "my_site/my_views_url/11"
(#11 is the tid of "fruits")

This url will list all terms depth to "fruits" (so apples, pears, bananas)

To add a depth in your argument term in the view follow the views UI :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Ok so I added the argument and changed the menu's link url to point to the category I want to display first, "fruits". I get a page with the content of fruits (apples, pears, bananas). What I'm missing now is a way to navigate between those categories (fruits, vegetables, meat). Adding menu items is not an option as I want this to be look and feel gallery-like

Comment: i suggest you to post an other question without slideshow (because your question's title is confusing) focus on your need : a view for a taxonomy tree with links with childrens terms

Comment: I edited this one along with its text. Hopefully it's more clear now...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Taxonomy VTN module](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_vtn) , but it subgroup with alphabets

[image]

> Taxonomy VTN module provides an index for vocabularies, terms and
>   nodes just like those you find at the end of reference or technical
>   books. It supports synonyms, terms, related terms, and parent/child
>   relations.

or may be this [module](https://drupal.org/project/vocabindex) you are looking for, it have the alphabetical sort order for the vocabulary.

[image]