# Embed Views Map in Slider/Slideshow

Tags: views, javascript

I need to have a slider on my main page that has a number of images (taken from views), and also a map that slides. Can anyone recommend any tutorials on how to embed a block as one of the images in a slider or any other solutions to this? So far everything that I have seen is just for embedding images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Views slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)** module :

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow **of any content (not
>   just images**) that can appear in a View... Potential uses :
>
> - **News item** slideshow (such as the title, image and teaser of the last 5 news articles submitted)
> - The **last X number of X submitted** (images, videos, blog entries, forum posts, comments, testimonials, etc.).
> - Rotate **hottest new products**, contact links, share links, entire nodes, categories, image galleries, etc.

There are many tutorials links on the project page , i.e how to [create a simple slideshow](https://drupal.org/node/1023940) with some node fields.

Define the relationship between your images & maps ( taxonomy ? fields of the same node ? ...), set a view showing them, then display it as a slideshow.

If you **can't find how to join** your content in a view query, have a look at [Multiple nodes in one slide using views slideshow or another module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76010/multiple-nodes-in-one-slide-using-views-slideshow-or-another-module) ...

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials for this that don't rely on storing the images as content? My data is read through views from an external database, and these seem to not apply to that situation.

Comment: Don't understand precisely your case, but this could be helpful : https://drupal.org/project/emfield , whether Embedded Image Field or Media:node... there are several subprojects. And once you have your third party content as a field put it in your view...