# Views - how to replace the pager with a slider

Tags: 7, javascript, views

I have a view of events, and want to display 10 events at a time.

Instead of the clicking the pager, I want the view to cycle to the next 10 events automatically after a set number of seconds - the view will be displayed on a monitor without user interaction.

The views_slideshow module only allows me to do this with every single item in the view. 
How would I best approach this - ideally with an existing module.

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This answer is similar - maybe some of the principles could be used: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76010/multiple-nodes-in-one-slide-using-views-slideshow-or-another-module?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Views Slideshow sounds like the ticket https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow. 
FlexSlider might do the same, but also responsively.